# Create CDFU in 2010 example?

Tags: 2010

Recently migrated from SP 2007 to 2010, the CDFU workflows did got well in the migration so I am rebuilding them.  The steps/logic must be different than SPD 2007.  Want to send point of contact an email task to select from a list of choices say Apples, Oranges, or Bananas.  I can get the email to fire off, the user can select the choice, but then the only value I am getting back seems like a ListID number.  I can't figure out how to pass the selection back to my project list.  I presumed the task list would show the selection but it doesn't  Is there something missing where the task list isn't being updated so I can't update the project list since the task list is null?  Anyone have screenshots or step by step of a simple CDFU??